# map subdomain from digital ocean to wordpress for blog

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I have a domain www.example.com running on digital ocean and hosts a spring app with nginx as proxy server.

I created a new blog on wordpress with free plan giving me example.home.blog domain.

I want to map my wordpress into digital ocean?

I tried adding CNAME in digital ocean as mentioned in the blog https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-create-subdomain-for-my-blog-on-digital-ocean

and then went to wordpress https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/ to map it. Wordpress is asking for 96$ annually. I dont understand this. Can someone explain what exactly should be done here?

Can i just create a sub domain in digital ocean and use nginx to point to wordpress? Would that be sufficient in terms of SEO?